# How to call javascript function in onchange event with spring form tag?

Tags: javascript, spring

I have a **`showCustomersList()`** javascript function in `FunctionBag.js` now I want to call that function in onchange event of the springs **`<form:select onchange="">`** tag in a jsp file.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I suppose jQuery .change() will do it just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how we do it in 2011.
use Jquery

```
$('#yourFormId select').change(function() {
    showCustomersList();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

`<form:select onchange="javascript:showCustomersList();">`